# recv with kivy -thearding - dont work

Tags: python, kivy

I did an app with kivy that sends data to the server in one class called `LoginScreen` and receives data from the server in another class called `Searchi`.

It doesn't work, I really don't know what is the problem and I don't got any errors.

my client:

```
# kivy.require("1.8.0")
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput  
from kivy.graphics import Line
from kivy.uix.button import Button
import socket
import threading

Builder.load_string("""
#: import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
<MenuScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Sign Up'
            on_press:
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
                root.manager.current = 'settings'
        Button:
            text: 'Login'
            on_press:
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
                root.manager.current = 'settings'

<Searchi>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'send massage'
            font_size: '20sp'
            size_hint: (0.4,0.111)
            pos_hint: {'y': 0,'x':0.6}
            on_press:
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
                root.manager.current = 'settings'


<SettingsScreen>:
     BoxLayout:
         FloatLayout:
            LoginScreen
            Button:
                font_size: '20sp'
                size_hint: (0.4,0.111)
                pos_hint: {'y': 0,'x':0.6}
                text: 'Back to menu'
                on_press:
                     root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
                     root.manager.current = 'menu'
""")


class LoginScreen(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2


        self.add_widget(Label(text='username'))
        self.username = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.username)

        self.add_widget(Label(text='Password'))
        self.password = TextInput(multiline=False, password=True)
        self.add_widget(self.password)

        self.submit_button = Button(text='sumbit',size_hint=(.5, 
.25),font_size=20)
        self.submit_button.bind(on_press=self.submit_username)
        self.add_widget(self.submit_button)

    def submit_username(self, *args):
        send_data(self.username.text)
        sm.current = 'searchi'
        sm.transition.direction = 'left'

def send_data(name):
    my_socket = socket.socket()
    my_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8088))
    my_socket.send(name.encode('utf-8'))
    my_socket.close()

def recv_data():
    my_socket = socket.socket()
    my_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8085))
    name=my_socket.recv(1024)
    msg = name.decode('utf-8')
    my_socket.close()
    return msg

# Declare both screens
class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SettingsScreen(Screen):
    pass

 class Searchi(Screen):
     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
         super(Searchi, self).__init__(**kwargs)
         self.msg=threading.Thread(target=recv_data).start()
         self.add_widget(self.msg)


 # Create the screen manager
 sm = ScreenManager()
 sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
 sm.add_widget(Searchi(name='searchi'))
 sm.add_widget(SettingsScreen(name='settings'))

class TestApp(App):
     def build(self):
          return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
     TestApp().run()
```

my server:

```
import socket
import db      # import my db
import threading


server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind(('127.0.0.1',8088))
server_socket.listen(5)


oldmsg = ""
while(True):
     (client_socket, client_address) = server_socket.accept()
     client_username = client_socket.recv(1024)
     msg = client_username.decode('utf-8')
     print(msg)

     if msg != oldmsg:
         db.data_entry_login(msg, "dsfsds", "dsfsfsdd", "2")  # insert to my db
        oldmsg=msg
        client_socket.send(msg.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: I think the problem might be the socket you are using to receive the message is not the socket that you used to send, try using the same one.